# SVG Pan around viewport - onclick/onmove keeps resetting?

Tags: javascript, html, svg

i posted this question earlier however it was a jumbled and made no real sense.
Also I've re hashed the code but i'm still getting the same issue.

To explain; i have an SVG element that i can current click on and drag about, this will works peachy and i'm, pleased with it, however once the user unclicks the mouse button and then goes and moves the mouse and starts the dragging functionality, the svg co-ords simply go back to 0 and the whole image just starts back at 0.0.

this is really buggin me now, i feel like i'm missing something simple.

edit: JSFiddle as requested - https://jsfiddle.net/2cu2jvbp/2/

Here is the code that i've "hashed" together:

```
var states = '',  stateOrigin;
var root = document.getElementById("svgCanvas");
var viewport = root.getElementById("viewport");

function setAttributes(element, attribute)
{
    for(var n in attribute) //rool through all attributes that have been created.
    {
     element.setAttributeNS(null, n, attribute[n]);   
    }
}

function setupEventHandlers() //self explanatory;
{
  setAttributes(root, {
      "onmousedown": "mouseDown(evt)", //do function
      "onmouseup": "mouseUp(evt)",
      "onmousemove":  "mouseMove(evt)", 
  }); 
}


function setCustomTransMatrix(element, a,b,c,d,e,f) {
    var m = "matrix(" + a + " " + b + " " + c + " " +d + " " + e + " " + f + ")";

    element.setAttribute("transform", m);
}

function getMousePoint(evt) { //this creates an SVG point object with the co-ords of where the mouse has been clicked.
    var points = root.createSVGPoint();

    points.x = evt.clientX;
    points.Y = evt.clientY;

    return points;
}


function mouseDown(evt)
{
    if(evt.target == root || viewport)
    {
     states = "pan";   
     stateOrigin = getMousePoint(evt);
    }   
}

function mouseMove(evt)
{
    var pointsLive = getMousePoint(evt);
    var storedCo = [];

    if(states == "pan")
    {
    setCustomTransMatrix(viewport, 1,0,0,1, pointsLive.x - stateOrigin.x, pointsLive.Y - stateOrigin.Y);
     storedCo[0] = pointsLive.x - stateOrigin.x
     storedCo[1] = pointsLive.Y - stateOrigin.Y;
    }

    else if(states == "store")
    {
        stateOrigin = pointsLive;
        states = "stop";
    }


}

function mouseUp(evt)
{
    if(states == "pan")
    {
     states = "store"; 
        if(states == "stop")
        {
         states ='';   
        }
    }
}

function intialize() {
    var matrik = root.getCTM();
    setupEventHandlers();
    console.log(matrik);
    //setCustomTransMatrix(viewport, matrik.a, matrik.b, matrik.c, matrik.d, matrik.e,matrik.f);
}

intialize();
```

Comment: it looks like your not updating "roots" placement? I could be wrong...

Comment: Literally no idea haha!  personally i think it's something todo with:                                                                 the setTranslate function creating a new instance of the translate which starts at 0 everytime.

Comment: Can you post all of your code on jsfiddle?

Comment: shere you go - http://jsfiddle.net/2cu2jvbp/

Comment: All of that code gives errors

Comment: If you fix it ill take a look, at work so i don't have time fix it all.

Comment: mmm yeah i don't know why that is! It's working on my local browser.

Comment: try now ^_^ https://jsfiddle.net/2cu2jvbp/2/